# Create objects for each plot in cadastral map

Tags: inkscape, smartobject, maps

[image: cadastral map]

I have this village cadastral map consisting of all plots in the village. The plots are numbered by their division and a sub-division. The numbers appear within the enclosed area of the plot.

I want to identify each plot's outline as an object (like a closed polygon).

My end purpose: I have this map georeferenced and overlaid on Google Custom Maps. I also have a spreadsheet with a few fields of information for each plot. I would like to reference the object as another field. Then upload this sheet in Google Custom Maps. Select any number of plots based on some criterion using the information about the plots.

The original cadastral map was in a dwg (autocad) format. I converted it into dxf format and then imported it into Inkscape.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Inkscape.
The source cadastral map was in dwg, converted it to dxf and then upload it to Inkscape.

Comment: You  might want to include that in your question (use the [edit] button), for the best solution is heavily dependent on the software used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way I know of to create polygons of all those lines would be to:

- make a new layer and put a copy of the dividing lines on it:

  - select one magenta line in the layer below, then right-click, then do 'select same' -> stroke color.
  - copy the selection (Ctrl+C), then select the new layer and paste in place with Ctrl+Alt+V
  - repeat for the cyan and any other interesting lines (black might need to be selected individually, as text and those circles are black, too).
- now select all lines in the new layer (Ctrl+A, or lock the other layer and drag a selection box with the mouse), and combine them into one object with Ctrl+K
- next, draw a large rectangle that covers the whole area
- now, put the rectangle below the lines in the new layer (PgDn)
- and finally, cut the rectangle into pieces by selecting both the combined lines and the rectangle, then doing Path > Division
- cleanup: remove the outer part, and check if all items have really been separated (e.g. by setting a minimum distance in the Object > Align and distribute dialog)